# Find the closed form of this summation series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

> Solve the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{3n+1}$$

I decided to open the series but could not form a closed form. Also, I think that it can be a Taylor expansion of any well-known function$?$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This reminds me loosely of the [Mercator series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series) / the [alternating harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Alternating_harmonic_series).
Also the [Leibniz formula for π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) seems very closely related. Maybe you can do something similiar to Leibniz's derivation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical technique is to utilize geometric series and interchange of series and integral:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{3n+1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{3n}}{3n+1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}(-x)^{3n}dx = \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-x)^{3n}dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^3}dx.$$

The last integral is elementary and can be computed by first using partial fractions.